# How to hide div using jquery or java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hide

Hello i would like to hide a span and a div if the value is 0.00..here is my code

```
<span class="price-old"> <%=getCurrentAttribute('item','custitem_sumisho_listprice')%>      </span>
<span class="price-new"><%=getCurrentAttribute('item','custitem_sumisho_onlineprice')%>  </span>
<div class="save-sale" style="font-size: .8em; padding-top: 4em"><%=getCurrentAttribute('item','custitem_sumisho_totalsave')%></div>
```

In the above code if the div of class="save-sale" will have 0.00 value then i would like to hide the class="price-old" and class="save-sale".Here getattribute tag will get the value of item price.

I have tried the below jquery but its not working

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/site/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
if ($(".save-sale").text() == "0.00") {
$(".save-sale").hide();
$(".price-old").hide();
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: but this is working http://jsfiddle.net/u98b4fzm/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are having multiple `save-sale` div, you can use `.each()` to iterate them all and check its value for making `save-sale` and `price-old` hidden.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/site/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
  $(".save-sale").each(function(){
  if ($(this).text().trim() == "0.00") {
       $(this).hide();
       $(this).prev(".prod-price").find(".price-old").hide();
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ygcx972y/9/)**

Comment: I just suggested another way to achieve same, but problem may be in jquery include otherwise code looks good.

Comment: have you checked any console errors? and verified that jQuery library path is correct and getting loaded in browser?

Comment: do i need to convert it to rounded value?

Comment: You can use `trim()` as suggested by Sanki in below answer or share a jsfiddle link with your problem statement to help you better. Also [these](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.in/2009/03/check-if-jqueryjs-is-loaded.html) are ways to check if jquery loaded or not.

Comment: may be there are lots of items and it will check the value one by one so is it a problem for script not running?

Comment: Do you have multiple div with class `save-sale`? if yes, then you can use id to this element and then ready its text.

Comment: yes multiple divs how to check value one by one and then hide those classes?

Comment: you can use `.each()` to iterate all divs and then hide that div and its previous price old div. See my updated answer

Comment: its working to hide save-sale class but not working to hide price-old class

Comment: is `price-old` span is at same position with respect to every `save-sale`? I mean are you having same repeated html structure as posted in question? Or you can share jsfiddle link with html having multiple `save-sale` div as you are having in your code, this will be useful to help you better.

Comment: it is something like this

Comment: <div class="prod-price">
<span class="price-old">11.80</span>
<span class="price-new">10.80</span>
</div>
<div class="save-sale" style="font-size: .8em; padding-top: 4em">1.00</div>

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zK5FN/717/)

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/site/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    if ($.trim($(".save-sale").text()) == "0.00") {
    $(".save-sale").hide();
    $(".price-old").hide();
  }
});
</script>
```

**For Multiple Divs with same classname you can try the following:**

```
$(function () {
$(".save-sale").each(function (i) {
    if ($.trim($(this).text()) == "0.00") {
        $(this).closest(".save-sale").hide();
        $(this).closest(".price-old").hide();
    }
     else{
        $(this).closest(".save-sale").show();
        $(this).closest(".price-old").show();
    }
});
});
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zK5FN/718/)

Comment: i have multiple divs with same class name how to apply this code on divs one by one to check values and hide classes

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> $(".class or #id").hide()

or something similar but with used css style

> $(".class or #id").css('display','none')

but if you want set this to all elements with class use obviously each function:

> $(".class").each(function()
>       {
>       $(this).css('display','none')
>       });